# Getting the value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I just need some ideas how i get the value from the dropdown

```
<select  id="ins" name="instructor" required>
    <?php
        //dropdown instructor name
        echo "<option  value=\"\">"."Select"."</option>";
        $qry = "select * from instructor";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option  value=".$row['insA_I'].">".$row['insname']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

and put the value in this .php file in `$_POST['instructor']`

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      require 'connection.php'; //connection

      $qry = "select course from instructor where insA_I = '".$_POST['instructor']."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
      $_SESSION['row'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $data = $_SESSION['row']['course'];
      echo $data;
   ?>
```

am still new in  ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#ins').change(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "json_php.php",
            data: '',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

i already searched this in internet but didn`t get my answer after some modifcation 
just need idea, techniques .etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this ajax code**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#ins').change(function(){

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "json_php.php",
                data: {instructor:$(this).val()},
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**php code for query**

```
$qry = "select course from instructor where insA_I = '".$_POST['instructor']."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
      $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $_SESSION['row']['course']=$fetch['course'];
      $data = $_SESSION['row']['course'];
      echo $data;
```

Comment: thnks for fast reply :D ..but i need query it to retrieve the course data base on my query

Comment: i tried and there`s an error 'illegal string offset 'course''

Comment: it worked now.. i removed the ['course'] in session but i dont get that {instructor:$(this).val()} this is not even in query. but anyway thnks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, use jQuery:

```
data: { instructor: $('#ins').val() }
```

Also, please note that your SQL query is ***wide open to SQL injection***.  [This is a good place to start reading about that](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).